# How To Break Up Company Website Into Groups To Manage Their Content

Tags: php, apache, joomla, content-management-system

I've been looking around and not finding any good answers.  I work at a small company.  They have a quick information website for internal users.  It needs updating but here is the situation.  I want each group to be able to manage their own page/s contents.  For instance HR to manage their documents, another group to manage the phone directory,etc.  I don't want them all to have to be trained or take training on any extensive software.  It doesn't even have to have a lot of features probably.  I've been looking at possibly Joomla as our group already knows PHP, Apache, etc.  But haven't really got a good feel if I can break the content up and assign certain areas to certain groups inside of it so they only have access to change their own content only.

Right now all of it's on one page and grew out of hand before I got here to 2 page list of items without a collapsible menu.   I do like that some areas all they have to do is drop files on a file share to update their items.  I may keep part of that, just break it up into separate pages instead of showing each in one single frame in the middle as you click on the menu item.   Since most of it is documents it's not all that bad.

Anyway looking for someone that's already been down this road and has a feeling for what I'm trying to do and how to go about it.

BTW prefer something open source if adding on any product to what we have.

Comment: Give every user a level of authorization in your database. When a user logs in, determine the content they can see by checking that level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joomla since version 1.6 has fine grained access control that you can customise your self.  Normally what I would do is create a user group for each of your groups. THen create a category tree for that group to make and manage their articles.  Then for each of these categories give members of the group permission to create, edit, delete or whatever you want them to have.
THere is a lot of documentation out there on how to do this. (Some by me :)) Just search for Joomla ACL or Joomla Access Control.

Comment: Thanks. I've just loaded Joomla on my PC to try out before i set it up on our Dev system.  In looking for Joomla ACL I did run across an extension called ACL Manager.  I may install that to see if it makes the process a little easier.   Right now just have the Joomla test site.  I may have to drop back and just build from the ground up.   if I run across anything like that ACL Manager or a doc that helps I'll share it.  Thanks

Comment: ACL manager can be helpful though it is not necessary.  Building from the ground up is going to be a lot more complex.  Just make your groups in the user manager and assign the users to the groups. It's really not hard.

Answer (score 0):

If you have using joomla, you have the choice to edit your mysql database, there are two tables you need to edit, one is users, the other is usergroup_map. Each group should have a group ID and its own permission. After you create a page, just assign the permission to the page. If you have more than 6 groups, you might also need to edit usergroup table to add more group ID

Comment: Maybe that is how you would do it in Joomla 1.5 or earlier. In no way should you be directly editing the database

Comment: Because you need to use the API to make sure all of the tables are in synch and further there is a user interface for making groups that will not create any problems, which direct editing will.

Comment: Well, you are right, directly editing database without changing php will crash joomla user function. Joomla has a list of powerful hooks, like $user = JFactory::getUser();
 $userId = $user->id;
 JUserHelper::setUserGroups($userId, 3); But anyway, for Michael to do what he wants, he must edit database. Either directly editing database with additional PDO,mysql,mysqli or just use the hooks

Comment: You use the APIs because they will correctly update the other tables at the same time. In the case of groups they are a nested set and you have to look at the lft, rgt and parent for them, as one example.  It's not a matter of go in, add a line and you are done.